# Which plugin try to clone some block?

Tags: minecraft

On my Minecraft server (Spigot 1.9.4) , I have some log sometimes.

```
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: 1 blocks cloned]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot access blocks outside of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
[10:18:15] [Server thread/INFO]: [@: Cannot summon the object out of the world]
```

But I don't know the origin of this log, i try verbose mode without success.
I have this log every 12 minutes and 48 seconds exactly !

```
28.06 09:52:39
28.06 10:05:27
28.06 10:18:15
```

My plugin list :

> Plugins (43): dynmap, WorldEdit, hNether, Skript, OpenInv, Essentials,
>   LogBlock, Lift, ClearLag, Craftconomy3, AutoMessage, Modifyworld,
>   Multiverse-Core, WorldGuard, ProtocolLib, BungeePortals, UberRecipes,
>   HorseProtect, Multiverse-SignPortals, VoxelSniper, EssentialsChat,
>   BlocksHub, PermissionsEx, BlocksHub-LogBlock, Multiverse-Portals,
>   SuperVanish, Vault, ChairStairs, EssentialsSpawn, BungeeTabListPlus,
>   JSONAPI, AreaShop, pvparena, TimeGivesYouMoney, MobArena,
>   PerWorldInventory, LWC, HolographicDisplays, QuickShop, Citizens,
>   Shopkeepers, BlocksHub-WorldGuard, Multiverse-NetherPortals

Someone did have the same problem ?
Do you know how trace this to the source ?

Thanks

Comment: That's a command block, most likely.

Comment: Okay, I try to unload every world actually unused, and i don't have anymore the log with clone.
I try to reload every world, for locate the world and after the command_block.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a command block being used, rather than a plugin.

On the "admin broadcast" that command blocks also trigger once someone uses an operator command, the "username" name it uses is `@`.